# 403 FORBIDDEN error while trying to insert an item in a SharePoint list

Tags: rest, ajax

Hi I am trying to insert a list item in a SharePoint list by using REST api. I am getting an error as:

```
{
    "readyState": 4,
    "responseText": "{\"error\":{\"code\":\"-2130575251, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException\",\"message\":{\"lang\":\"en-US\",\"value\":\"The security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted. Please use your web browser's Back button to try your operation again.\"}}}",
    "responseJSON": {
        "error": {
            "code": "-2130575251, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException",
            "message": {
                "lang": "en-US",
                "value": "The security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted. Please use your web browser's Back button to try your operation again."
            }
        }
    },
    "status": 403,
    "statusText": "FORBIDDEN"
}
```

I used the following code:

```
function addData() {

    var listUrl = "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('QuestionsList')/Items";

    var studID = $("#stID").val();
    var optionVal = $(".rdBtn").val();

    alert(listUrl);

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://myserverAndSiteName" + listUrl,

        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            __metadata: {
                type: "SP.Data.StudentResponseListItem"
            },
            StudentID: $("#stID").val(),
            QuestionNumber: qno,
            Question: question,
            StudentAnswer: $(".rdBtn").val()
        }),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", // return data format  
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $("#tblEmployees").empty();
            getItem(listUrl);
            alert("Successfully Submitted");
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I suggest to check digest, are you sure that you are retrieving it correctly?

Comment: As suggested by @RiccardoGDev, make sure that your request digest value is not empty. If it is empty/null, you can make a POST request to "YourwebURL/_api/contextinfo" and get the request digest value. And then Use this rewuest digest value in your subsequent request.

Comment: The digest is correct. Actually, the target list name was in correct and I forgot to write ListItem after the list name in the " type: "SP.Data........" attribute. Thank you all for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

1. open an elevated command prompt:

   a) Go to start and type in cmd in the search box.

   b) Right click on the command prompt and click run as administrator.
2. Now reset your TCP/IP stack:

   a) Type the following commands (**see below**) in the command prompt, each followed by pressing enter.

   b) Restart the computer.
3. Now open Internet Explorer and check if you can access the website.

```
ipconfig /flushdns
nbtstat -R
nbtstat -RR
netsh int reset all
netsh int ip reset
netsh winsock reset
Exit
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Actually, the target list name was in correct and I forgot to write ListItem after the list name in the " type: "SP.Data........" attribute.